# How to grab the invoking saga from within a saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Lets say we have

```
function* saga1() {
  yield call(saga2)
}

function* saga2() {
  debugger;
}
```

Whats the best way to visualize how sagas are setup/structured.

Comment: `Whats the best way to visualize how sagas are setup/structured.` I'm not sure what you mean by that... are you trying to make a dependency graph or something?

Comment: @NicholasTower Or just through debugging find out what's calling the current saga.